# How to restrict repeater rows in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a asp.net repeater control .I have to display only two rows in the repeater .but my dataset has 10 rows ..is there a way to restrict the number of rows of a repater ?

Comment: just project from the old DS into a filtered DS, and bind to that. ie repeater.DataSource = someDataSet.Take(10).ToList()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would Take the appropriate number of rows from your original DataSet

I don't have my IDE in front of me, but the idea is something like

```
Repeater1.DataSource = MyDataSet.Take(2).ToList();
```

Alternatively if you need to sort it, you could try something like this

```
Repeater1.DataSource = (from ds in MyDataSet
                        select ds
                        orderby SomeValue descending).Take(2);
```

You can also skip the first X rows and then return 2

```
Repeater1.DataSource = MyDataSet.Skip(20).Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: sorry didn't see the comment. I just thought about it after I made my original post. NOTE: all credit to the first option be to RPM :-p

Comment: also, sorry for hacking this together.. I keep having to go back to the code converter since I'm a VB guy :(

Comment: Great Stuff and Easy solution. Helps me a lot when implementing the Custom Pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the PagedDataSource class, this class encapsulates the paging related properties of a data-bound control.